# Flexbox container with long contents overflows out of parent container even after using overflow: scroll

Tags: html, css

```css
.modal {
  border: 3px dotted green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.modalContents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.topContents {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
  
.bottomContents {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modalContents">
    <div class="topContents">
         top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top 
    </div>
    <div class="bottomContents">
        bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to let `.bottomContents` div located bottom of modal div, and `.topContents` div takes all rest spaces. But as you see, because of length of `.topContents` div, contents overflows.

How can I make it not overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `height:100%;` on `.modalContents` and `.topContents`, if no height it will just stretch.

```css
.modal {
  border: 3px dotted green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.modalContents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%;
}

.topContents {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
  height:100%;
}
  
.bottomContents {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modalContents">
    <div class="topContents">
         top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top top 
    </div>
    <div class="bottomContents">
        bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is meaning of height: 100% in .topContents?

Comment: if you dont add it that would not change much in this structure. But I dont know which structure you are trying to implement. so I added but relly not needed if you just gonna add text.